# Using bash calculator in a vim script - strange behaviour

Tags: bash, vim, cygwin, bc

Does anybody know why this works with bash calculator (`bc`) in `vim`:

```
echo system ("echo 3+5 \| dos2unix \| bc -l") ---> output: 8   
echo system ("echo 3/5 \| dos2unix \| bc -l") ---> output: .600000000000000  
echo system ("echo 3*5 \| dos2unix \| bc -l") ---> output: 15
```

but this not:

```
echo system ("echo 2^5 \| dos2unix \| bc -l") ---> output: 25  
echo system ("echo 3^5 \| dos2unix \| bc -l") ---> output: 35
```

This is used under cygwin in Windows.

Comment: I don't know why, but have you tried to escape the ^-character. For example echo system ("echo 2\^5 \| dos2unix \| bc -l")

Comment: It looks like the `^` is causing problems. On my Mac, `2^5` is interpreted as `255` and on your PC it is interpreted as `25`. Not sure how to fix it besides playing around with multiple `^`.

Comment: @Ahe, yes I tried to escape the ^ character. Same output.

Comment: @Romain, yes with 4 `^` characters it works. `2^^^^5` --> output: `32`, but why?

Comment: It's the first time I run into this behavior. I have no idea what would be the cause.

Comment: I think it has something to do with Vim's somewhat archaic input system. The command line likely interprets `^5` as `Ctrl+5` which produces `5`. It sucks. Did you know that Vim can do some calculations? While you are inserting text, hit `<C-r>=2+5<CR>`. It doesn't do `^`, though, but you can use `pow()`: `:<C-r>=pow(2,5)<CR>`.

Comment: @romainl If you input `^` then `5` you will *never* get `<C-5>`, same for any `^{Char}`. If you are not using mappings you won’t even get `<C-c>` treated specially (unless it is `\<C-c>` inside double quoted string of course). Vim archaic input system is not ever used when calling functions. In any case, vim does not support `<C-5>`, so there is no way to get `^5` shown in a special color by `<C-v><C-5>` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the value of `&shell` option? It must be `/path/to/cygwin/bash`, not something ending with `cmd.exe`. The problem is that `^` is an escape character in windows `cmd.exe`, so `echo 2^5` is somewhat equivalent to `echo 2\5` resolving into `echo 25`.

If it is `cmd.exe` add a line

```
set shell=/path/to/cygwin/bash
```

to your vimrc.

Note though that `echo 2^^^^5` resolving to `echo 2^5` is somewhat strange (in plain `cmd.exe` it is `echo 2^^5`), but I saw very long discussion on vim-dev regarding escaping issues for `cmd.exe` some time ago, so it may be one of them. Should not happen on the most recent vim (or it is a bug).

Comment: hi Zyx, you're absolutely right. The shell was the windows shell. I installed bash calculator months ago also in windows (gnu bc). You're right echo 2^^5 works also. 2^5 not, 2^^^5 not, 2^^^^5 works also.

Comment: Zyx, I was wrong yesterday. `2^^5` (two carets) doesn't work (it gives an answer but not the correct one). The only one which works is 4 carets. `2^^^^5`.